# How do I create a Google Cloud VM instance with an ext4 filesystem?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a CentOS 7 VM instance through Compute Engine -> VM instances, and it came with xfs by default.  I see from [this page](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/supported-filesystems#ext4) that Google Cloud supports ext4, but I don't see any option to specify it when creating a VM instance.  Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automate GCP persistent disk initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162620/automate-gcp-persistent-disk-initialization)

Comment: @Asdfg - Your link does not provide information on how to create a boot disk with ext4. Google Compute Engine images are "block" images of preconfigured systems. That means you cannot change/specify/modify the file system of the boot image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc you share is for COS, not for CentOS or any other OS. In particular you can [set `ext4` for additional disks](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/filers-on-compute-engine#persistent-disks) you attach to your VM but not for the boot disk.

So the short answer is No.